# How to kill running application in android

Tags: android

I am writing a application which can kill other running application. For this I am using following code

```
int pid = process.pid;
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
Log.e("killed",process.processName);
```

I am able to display all running application. But the above two line of code is not killing the process of application(com.sample.mango). Also I can see several task killing app in the market.

So my question is -- Is it possible to kill running application from other application?

If yes then what is way to kill? (why the above code is not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Android allows these kind of apps? Isn't this a service provided by operating system rather then third party App. I would hate if my app is getting killed by some third party App.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29):

> Kill the process with the given PID. Note that, though this API allows
>   us to request to kill any process based on its PID, the kernel will
>   still impose standard restrictions on which PIDs you are actually able
>   to kill. Typically this means only the process running the caller's
>   packages/application and any additional processes created by that app;
>   packages sharing a common UID will also be able to kill each other's
>   processes.

That's why killProcess does not work.

You should try [killBackgroundProcesses](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses%28java.lang.String%29) instead. Don't forget to add `KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` to your AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [sending](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#sendSignal%28int,%20int%29) [SIGNAL_KILL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#SIGNAL_KILL) to the pids.